# Publishing a gitflow feature branch to gerrit

Tags: git, branch, push, gerrit, git-flow

I use Gerrit and gitflow, and I would like to push my giflow feature branches to Gerrit. When I use a simple

```
git flow feature publish feature_name
```

Gerrit rejects the push because I'm trying to push to the **feature/feature_name** branch, which is not allowed. I would like to push to **refs/for/feature/feature_name** instead and create this remote branch if it does not exist.

In my git configuration, I tried to set

```
[branch "feature/feature_name"]
    merge = refs/for/feature/feature_name
```

but this setting is ignored when I publish using gitflow.

Is there a way to set the remote branch using gitflow's *feature publish* command?

Answer (score 3):

Me and a colleague of mine did some changes for git-flow so it works with gerrit, unfortunatly you have to have force push rights in certain branch areas, but other wise it works fine

I can talk to my colleague and then we can publish the fork

I will start to take out company specific source and push back a fork to github 
tueday morning Beijng time

Finally You can checkout this fork of git-flow https://github.com/RasmusVoss/gitflow

There is a few items that you need to read up on. https://github.com/RasmusVoss/gitflow/wiki

To see the difference between regular git-flow and this version, This version is mainly for developers working with Gerrit, we are not using any releasing features of git-flow yet.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't.

The software has the remote name reference hardcoded like `refs/heads/$BRANCH`

I just read a [wiki page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User%3aDAndreescu/GitFlowGerrit) that talks about the tricky parts of integrating git-flow and gerrit. You might want to read that as well.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. This is what I was afaid of. I'll read the wiki page and hope for more insight.